# Расстановка блоков с помощью css

Tags: html, css

Нужно отодвинуть 3-й div, как на рисунке, но у меня почему-то не срабатывает `nth-child`, что я делаю не так?

```css
.apply__items{
 width: 180px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #2f383b;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 150px;
}

.apply__items:nth-child(2) {
 margin-left: 43px;
}

.apply__items:nth-child(3) {
 margin-right: 50px;
}

.apply__digit{
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 line-height: 80px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #2f383b;
 font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 400px;
 color: #2f383b;
}

.apply__digit:hover{
 border: none;
 background: #2f383b;
 color: #fff;
}

.apply__item{
 margin-top: 14px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #2f383b;
}
```

```html
<div class="apply__items">
   <div class="apply__digit">1</div>
   <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
</div>
<div class="apply__items">
   <div class="apply__digit">2</div>
   <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
</div>
<div class="apply__items">
   <div class="apply__digit">3</div>
   <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: он у вас срабатывает, что пишете, то и происходит

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы прописали - работает, работает именно так, как вы прописали. И чтобы получить такую картинку таким способом, нужно знать на какую ширину вы ее делаете. То есть работать это будет только для фиксированной ширины. Чтобы добиться такого разряженного заполнения адаптивно, можно воспользоваться флексбоксом:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.apply__items {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2f383b;
}

.apply__digit {
  margin:auto;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #2f383b;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  color: #2f383b;
}

.apply__digit:hover {
  border: none;
  background: #2f383b;
  color: #fff;
}

.apply__item {
  margin-top: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2f383b;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="apply__items">
    <div class="apply__digit">1</div>
    <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
  </div>
  <div class="apply__items">
    <div class="apply__digit">2</div>
    <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
  </div>
  <div class="apply__items">
    <div class="apply__digit">3</div>
    <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.apply__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2f383b;
}

.apply__items:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: red solid;
  border-right: red solid;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.apply__digit {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #2f383b;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  color: #2f383b;
}

.apply__digit:hover {
  border: none;
  background: #2f383b;
  color: #fff;
}

.apply__item {
  margin-top: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2f383b;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="apply__items">
    <div class="apply__digit">1</div>
    <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
  </div>
  <div class="apply__items">
    <div class="apply__digit">2</div>
    <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
  </div>
  <div class="apply__items">
    <div class="apply__digit">3</div>
    <div class="apply__item">Лучший код</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.apply__items:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Вы делаете все хорошо, только ширина бровсера маленькая:
Я меняю ширину в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds933qor/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]